# Solution to installion failure due to invalid APK file

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt

My logcat code:
http://txt.do/ku68

I tried solutions from other posts, but it is still not working.

**[EDIT]**

My manifest.xml:
http://txt.do/ku6e

Comment: Can you show your `manifest.xml`

Comment: plz post your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Without posting the `Manifest` file one solution might be using the full path of your provider in authorities Tag in `Manifest` file:

```
<provider android:name=".MessagesForegroundProvider"
   android:authorities="com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider"
```

Comment: where will i post this?